# How to find the last line and the diff of each line

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to handle the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
                   'sum':[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,]})
```

Now I want to find the difference from the last row by each ID.

Specifically, I tried this code.

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['sum'].diff(-1)
df
```

[image]

However, this would require a difference from one line behind.

Is there any way to determine the difference between each of the last rows with groupbuy?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add the expected output (as text) in the question for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform('last')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the last value per group:

```
df['diff'] = df['sum'].sub(df.groupby('ID')['sum'].transform('last'))
```

or using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['sum'].apply(lambda x: x-x.iloc[-1])
```

output:

```
    ID  sum  diff
0    1    1    -1
1    1    2     0
2    2    1    -1
3    2    2     0
4    3    1    -2
5    3    2    -1
6    3    3     0
7    4    1    -3
8    4    2    -2
9    4    3    -1
10   4    4     0
```

Comment: You use the apply function. Thank you!